# How to apply rounded corners to window in node-webkit?

Tags: rounded-corners, node-webkit

I can't apply rounded corners for frameless window in my desktop app. Adding border-radius property to html or body tags does not help.

I'm using latest node-webkit prebuilt binary (v0.8.4) for Windows.

I wish to place an iPad image as a window, but white background at all corners deface application. I hope someone has already faced with that problem and found a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to a recent update, that shipped in **node-webkit 0.11.2**, it's now possible.

You can make the node-webkit window transparent by adding `transparent: true` under the ***window*** section of your ***package.json*** file. Another optional addition would be `frame: false` which will remove the default OS header as well as hide the node-webkit toolbar.

Now that you have a transparent window you can emulate rounded corners. Depending on your code you'll have to add a `border-radius` to elements that affect the edge of your window.

The simplest way to emulate a bare-bones rounded window is by adding a `border-radius` to your `html` tag, with a `background-color` applied to your `body` tag.

Comment: border-radius doesn't seem to work (version 0.12.0). I have: "toolbar": false, "frame": false, "transparent": true. And in index.html: <body style="background-color:rgba(23,96,128,0.8); border-radius: 15px;">. The transparency is working however. Am I missing something?

Comment: Re my last comment I was able to solve by using a nested div: <body style="background: transparent;"><div style="background-color:rgba(23,96,128,0.8); border-radius: 10px; width:100%; height: 100%">

Comment: @ErezCohen My explanation was a bit vague with regards to where the `border-radius` should be. If you put the `border-radius` on your `html` tag instead of the `body` it should work, removing the need for a nested `div`. Where and how the `border-radius` is used to mimic a rounded window will heavily depend on how you format your page. I'll edit my answer in an attempt to make the use of rounding more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible yet. More information here: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/132

Comment: That's okay, if you have more questions about node-webkit stuff i suggest you look [here](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki)